# Config symfony2 firewall to block all users except guests

Tags: security, symfony, acl, firewall

This seem to be a simple question but I could not find any answer so far. What I want to do is **blocking logged-in users** to specific paths (login, register,...). Logically those paths ***must be allowed*** for guests (non-login users).

My question is:

1. Is it possible to be configured only inside `security.yml`? If yes, how?
2. If no, are there more convenient ways (e.g: I can config all such permissions/paths in one place like what I am doing in `security.yml`) to achieve that result without using `$securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER')` in each path?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using symfony 2.4, then there is a way you can specify this in the security.yml file.  The the docs [Securing by expression](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-by-an-expression).

Basically, in your `access_control` section, you can have a `allow_if` entry that allows you to have a custom conditional expression.

You can use an expression similar to this:

allow_if: "not is_authenticated()"